# How can I pause a CUDA stream and then resume it?

Tags: cuda, cuda-streams

Suppose we have two CUDA streams running two CUDA kernels on a GPU at the same time. How can I pause the CUDA kernel running with the instruction I putting in the host code and resume it with the instruction in the host code?
I have no idea how to write a sample code in this case, for example, to continue this question.

Exactly my question is whether there is an instruction in CUDA that can pause a CUDA kernel running in a CUDA stream and then resume it?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible to "pause" a running CUDA kernel. All the stream-based functions are available [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html).

Comment: Is the CUDA kernel run once and you really want to interrupt it, or multiple times and you want the break between invocations?

Comment: The `suspendDevice` function could be a way to do it? https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/debugger-api/group__EXEC.html#group__EXEC Otherwise rewrite your kernel to several smaller kernels or check a flag from inside the kernel, when to store the state and terminate. Please also tell us, why you want to pause? To get more performance to the first kernel or e.g. just to wait for more data. In the second case the kernel could keep running, but do nothing for some time.

Comment: @Sebastian, CUDA kernels run once. I have two CUDA streams that each run a kernel, these two kernels run at the same time and I want one of those two CUDA streams to pause running its kernel if a condition occurs and continue whenever I want.

Comment: Could you say, whether you want to pause for performance reasons (e.g. should the other kernel then run faster)? Do your kernels have many blocks (much more than multiprocessors on the GPU)? How complicated is the state of the threads, can it be manually saved?

Comment: What you want is called preemption, if done automatically; there are documented uses of it (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-high-priority-stream-preemption/78183) and undocumented and not guaranteed ways (https://github.com/vancemiller/CUDA-preemption). Preemption is not meant as a user feature. The GPU does it in certain situations. Better would be, if you could get the same result with a different way. Therefore my questions to your specific use case.

Comment: @Sebastian, Yes, for the same reasons you said I want to do this (run the other kernel faster). I do not understand what you mean by "How complicated is the state of the threads, can it be manually saved?".

Comment: First assign a higher priority to the continuously running stream. Then both kernels must handle this. The running kernel must distribute its work to more resources, whereby the paused kernel has to do less. This can best be done by having more blocks and pausing at block granularity. E.g. if you have 30 SMs in your GPU, instead of running the kernels once with 30 blocks each, run them with 1000 (smaller) blocks per grid each. Or even better, call the same kernel 33 times with 30 blocks each.

Comment: Can you please give more information? Which GPU? What launch configuration? How many blocks, threads per block for each of the both kernels? What is the runtime? Microseconds, Milliseconds, Seconds, Minutes? Do the kernels interact with the remaining system before they are finished? Or with each other?

Comment: @Sebastian, II am using GPU 1070 and CUDA toolkit 11.3. time of solo execution of the first kernel: 4184.25 milliseconds and time of solo execution of the second kernel: 3635.83 milliseconds and simultaneous execution time of the kernels: 7690.86 milliseconds. Kernels do not interact with each other.

Comment: @Sebastian, kernel1<<<128, 256>>()  and  kernel2<<<819200, 256>>>()

Comment: @Sebastian, In the usual installation of CUDA toolkit 11.3 on Linux operating system 18.04. (benchmark1) usr/local/cuda-11.3/samples/6_Advanced/scalarProd  and (benchmark2) usr/local/cuda-11.3/samples/0_Simple/inlinePTX. I run the kernel function in these two benchmarks simultaneously. In addition, the data volume is 800 MB per kernel.

Comment: The second one, you can change to `for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) kernel2<<<800, 256>>>(i);` and inside the kernel: `int blockid = i * 800 + blockIdx.x;` The overhead for starting the kernel lots of time for the different blocks is surprisingly low. Now give the streams priorities and redesign the for loop again. Only put new kernel2 calls into the stream, if no pause condition occured and the stream pipeline is empty. This you can do with synchronizing the stream with the CPU. (A better - more complicated - way would be with events and callbacks). Put the for loop into a separate CPU thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic parallelism with parameters for communication with host for the signals. Then launch a parent kernel with only 1 cuda thread and let it launch child kernels continuously until work is done or signal is received. If child kernel does not fully occupy the GPU, then it will lose performance.

```
__global__ void parent(int * atomicSignalPause, int * atomicSignalExit, Parameters * prm)
{
       int progress = 0;
       while(checkSignalExit(atomicSignalExit) && progress<100)
       {
           while(checkSignalPause(atomicSignalPause))
           {
                 child<<<X,Y>>>(prm,progress++);
                 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
           }
       }
}
```

There is no command to pause a stream. For multiple GPUs, you should use unified memory allocation for the communication (between GPUs).

To overcome the gpu utilization issue, you may invent a task queue for child kernels. It pushes work N times (roughly enough to keep GPU efficient in power/compute), then for every completed child kernel it increments a dedicated counter in the parent kernel and pushes a new work, until all work is complete (while trying to keep concurrent kernels at N).

Maybe something like this:

```
// producer kernel
// N: number of works that make gpu fully utilized
while(hasWork)
{
     // concurrency is a global parameter
     while(checkConcurrencyAtomic(concurrency)<N)
     {
         incrementConcurrencyAtomic(concurrency);

         // a "consumer" parent kernel will get items from queue
         // it will decrement concurrency when a work is done             
         bool success = myQueue.tryPush(work, concurrency);
         if(success)
         {
            // update status of whole work or signal the host
         }
     }

     // synchronization once per ~N work
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
     ... then check for pause signals and other tasks
}
```

If total work takes more than a few seconds, these atomic value updates shouldn't be a performance problem but if you have way too many child kernels to launch then you can launch more producer/consumer (parent) cuda-threads.